# How to pass data to MainActivity from chained child's child activity directly

Tags: java, android, android-intent

MainActivity contains button.
  On clicking button will go to Activity 2 .
  Activity 2 has button which on submitting takes to 3rd activity.
  3rd activity has done button which should take me to MainActivity and displays     data fetched from 2 and 3rd. Activity 3 should not go back to Activity 2.

My Approach:-

From  Mainactivity staring Activity2

```
 Intent activity2Intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, activity2.class);
 startActivityForResult(activity2Intent, INTENT_COUNTRY_REQUEST);
```

From Activity 2 I am again starting Activity3 and passing data as well

```
`Intent Activity3Intent = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
Activity3.putExtra("Position", mPosition);
Activity3.putExtra("CName", mCName);
Activity3Intent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
startActivity(Activity3Intent);`
```

In activity 3 I am using value from activity to relevant data  and then on submitting done, sending all this databack to MainActivity.

```
 Intent goMainActivity =    new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    goMainActivity .putExtra("SName", mSName);
    goMainActivity .putExtra("CNme", mCName);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, goMainActivity );   
    boolean foundHome = navigateUpTo(goMainActivity );
    finish();
```

Main activity has onActivityResult method which checks data, but it gets never fetches.

Can anyone suggest me how should I send data back to MainActivity.navigateUpTo takes me to MainActivity but data is never passed.

Thanks in advance.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: try  [My below Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42171973/6676466)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Try
Creating and extending the base `android.app.Application` class and define global variable in it and then you can get or set values in the application context.

```
public class Globalvar extends Application {

    private String mSName;

    public String getSmSName() {
        return mSName;
    }

    public void setmSName(String mSName) {
        this.mSName = mSName;
    }
}
```

In your android manifest you have to declare the class implementing android.app.Application

```
<application 
  android:name=".Globalvar" 
  android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
  android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Then to get or set

```
// set
((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).setmSName("foo");

// get
String s = ((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).getmSName();
```

**Previous Answer**

In `MainActivity`, in `onCreate()` method, you have to retrieve the Bundle (that contains all the data sent by the calling activity)

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String sname = bundle.getString("SName");
    String cname = bundle.getString("CNme");
```

Comment: I have tried this but 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference.

Comment: try retrieving values sent from activity 2 in activity 3, if retrieved, assign those values to some variable then pass it to MainActivity

Comment: In activity 3, onCreate method, i am getting values of activity2 storing them and then passing those values in onclick done method of Activity 3.In activity 3 im passing these values to main activity.But Main activity is not fetching anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your onActivityResult will never get called from 3rd Activity, Because you are starting 2nd Activity with `startActivityForResult` and you are trying to bypass 2nd Activity.

Try below code for your solution.

**MainActivity.java**

```
Intent activity2Intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, activity2.class);
startActivity(activity2Intent);
```

**activity2.java**

```
Intent Activity3Intent = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
Activity3.putExtra("Position", mPosition);
Activity3.putExtra("CName", mCName);
Activity3Intent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
startActivity(Activity3Intent);
```

Here is your Main Task

**activity3.java**

```
Intent goMainActivity =    new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
goMainActivity .putExtra("callingFrom", activity3);
goMainActivity .putExtra("SName", mSName);
goMainActivity .putExtra("CNme", mCName);
startActivity(goMainActivity);
ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this);
```

Now you have to only check in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()`

```
String callingFrom = bundle.getString("callingFrom");
if(callingFrom.equalsIgnoreCase("activity3"))
{
    // now get your othere parameters and do your work with them.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this

One use Activity  `android:launchMode=""` in Manifest file here you have take data by intent don't use `startActivityForResult` this will run only when back press from one activity to other

Two use `SharedPreferences` save it each Activity

Three combine both `android:launchMode` and `SharedPreferences` without using intent data

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

**MainActivity.java**

```
Intent activity2Intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(activity2Intent, INTENT_COUNTRY_REQUEST);
```

**activity2.java**  when opening Activity3 finish Activity2 and start Activity3 with "startActivityForResult"

```
Intent Activity3Intent = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
Activity3.putExtra("Position", mPosition);
Activity3.putExtra("CName", mCName);
startActivityForResult(activity2Intent, INTENT_COUNTRY_REQUEST);
finish();
```

**activity3.java** return result, this result will go to MainActivity's OnActivityResult(), don't start a new MainActivity.

```
Intent resultIntent =    new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("SName", mSName);
resultIntent.putExtra("CNme", mCName);
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

Now you will get your data in `MainActivity`'s `onActivityResult()`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == INTENT_COUNTRY_REQUEST
                && data != null) {
            String SName = data.getExtras().getString("SName");
            String CNme= data.getExtras().getString("CNme")
        }
    }

}
```